# trying to keep my node app alive on server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, deployment, continuous-deployment

I put my first application online in a ec2 server, the t2 micro.
actually, when i open the server with ssh and run

```
node index.js
```

the system works fine. with no delay.

to keep the app online, i use pm2 to my app still working when i close my ssh connection.

```
pm2 start index.js
```

but, when more hours go by, slower my application gets, until it crashs.

i tried  forever either, but happens the same thing. i think the hardware is not enough to run forever or pm2 with my application.

keeping that in mind, what other ways could I keep my application alive?

i tried nohup too, but stops when i close the ssh connection

Comment: Was you able to collect any log? if yes, you can post it here to allow others to help you.

Comment: have you thought about using supervisord, as that would restart the app should it fail